# Getting scroll of element in svelte

Tags: svelte

I have a div with style `overflow: scroll` and it is overflowing on the X-axis.
I would like to get the value of how far left/right the user has scrolled within this element, but I can't really figure it out.

I saw that you can quite easily bind the window scroll, but as it is just an element that is scrolling and not the window this won't work.
https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-window-bindings

so I tried binding the element, but couldn't really get any meaningful data out of it.

```
<script>
  let content;
</script>

<div class="carousel">
  <div class="content" bind:this={content}>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
{#if content}
{content.scrollLeft}
{/if}
```

is it at all possible and am I just missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to find the scroll left of the container/carousel. Not for content. below code will work. check this [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/7ef5191d72634f5a96e8d1981b91f506?version=3.29.4)

```
<script>
  let carousel, sleft;
</script>

<div class="carousel" bind:this={carousel} 
on:scroll={()=>sleft=carousel.scrollLeft}>
  <div class="content" >
    ...
  </div>
</div>

{#if carousel}
{sleft}
{/if}
```

Comment: Or use the event's target: `<div class="carousel" on:scroll){(e)=>sleft=e.target.scrollLeft}>...</div>` if you rather not bind the element.

Comment: I would suggest updating this to @razvan-tanase 's answer

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone wants to bind the **vertical** AND the **horizontal** scrolling pixels of an element:

- `element.scrollLeft`: horizontal pixels from left
- `element.scrollTop`: vertical pixels from top

[Here's a REPL with a working example](https://svelte.dev/repl/97366319dc7c477989fe744d01d81391?version=3.39.0)

- [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) is a list of all the properties and methods available to html elements
- Here's the Svelte API documentation for [binding elemental properties](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element_property)

```
<script>
  let box
  let xScroll = 0
  let yScroll = 0

  function parseScroll() {
    xScroll=box.scrollLeft
    yScroll=box.scrollTop
  }
</script>

<div class="box" bind:this={box} on:scroll={parseScroll}>
  ...
  (scrollable content)
  ...
</div>

<div class='report'>
  <div>horizontal: {xScroll}</div>
  <div>vertical: {yScroll}</div>
</div>
```